# Pass a php call to javascript variable?

Tags: php, javascript, variables, geojson

How to pass a call for example:

```
http://localhost/conn.php?geotable=INFR&geomfield=the_geom&srid=&fields=&parameters=&orderby=&sort=&limit=&offset=
```

into the javascript variable? Result of this call is string (geoJSON format lines).

Please help, I don't know what to try anymore!

Comment: you want to extract the url parameters from a string?

Comment: I think you need to explain yourself better, you want to save the result of that call on a variable (like ajax) or access the `get`variables in the url with javascript like you would in php?

Comment: yes, I want to save result of that call into a javascript variable.

Comment: "I don't know what to try anymore" - perhaps you should tell us what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could do this.  Here are a few options:

(Note: For purposes of demonstration, these examples assume that your PHP script returns the [GeoJSON Spec Example Code](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#examples).)

- AJAX: For doing AJAX calls, I recommend using a library, like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/), because it means you don't have to worry about all of the peculiarities of different browser versions.  If you use jQuery, the function you need to use is [`$.getJSON()` (see docs for more examples)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).  Your call might look like this:

  ```
  var path = http://localhost/conn.php?geotable=INFR&geomfield=the_geom&srid=&fields=&parameters=&orderby=&sort=&limit=&offset=

  var result;
  $.getJSON(path, function(data) {
      result = data;
  });
  ```

  This will receive the GeoJSON data from the server and copy it to the `result` variable.
- If you can modify the server-side script, the **easiest** way to do what you want is probably with [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  Modify the PHP code on the server so it takes a `callback` parameter and returns the JSON data wrapped inside a function with that name.  For example, if you set `callback=process`, the server will return the following:

  ```
  process(
      { "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
          { "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
            "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
            },
      .....
      }
  );
  ```

  (Note that this is exactly the same data as the sample linked above, just with `process(` before it and `);` after it.)

  All you need to get the data is some code like this:

  ```
  <script>
      var result;
      function process(received) {
          result = data;
      }
  </script>
  <script src="http://localhost/conn.php?callback=process&geotable=INFR&geomfield=the_geom&srid=&fields=&parameters=&orderby=&sort=&limit=&offset="></script>
  ```

Comment: Ok, let me be honest, I'm beginner with javascript and php and I need to store result of that call which is some points in geojson format, something like this feature collection: http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id14 and save that data into some variable, like it's written ***var result = { "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
      "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
      },*** So that text needs to be stored in variable 'result' for example. That text is RESULT of that call.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your GET variables available in javascript you could do something like this.

```
<script>
<?php 
echo 'var phpData = ' . json_encode($_GET);
?>
</script>
```

Make sure this code is before the part where you start using your javascript.
You can call your variable in javascript like this:

```
phpData.var
```

For example this part of your get ?geotable=INFR would be called in javascript using phpData.geotable

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I think he wants the JSON content from the URL, not the parts of the query string.

Comment: Ah i see he want's to call the url and then pass the return value to javascript again. Well it looks like conn.php is a local script he could apply the same tactic. Or use a curl request and catch the result then json encode the result into a js object.

Comment: Please read my comment up..